# Postfix - дублирование писем

Tags: linux, email, postfix

Добрый всем день. Необходимо дублировать исходящие и входящие письма со всех почтовых ящиков в отдельный, причём раскладывать по папкам. Все входящие письма в папку "Входящие", а все исходящие письма в папку "Отправленные" нового ящика.

Сейчас у меня сделано вот так

```
always_bcc = relay@site.ru
```

И все письма, какими бы они ни были, помещаются в папку "Входящие".

Заранее благодарю за ответ.

Comment: раскладывание файлов с сообщениями по imap-каталогам (как следует даже из названия) — не должно входить в круг задач smtp-сервера. используйте какой-нибудь фильтр вместо непосредственного сохранения файлов — procmail, sieve и т.д. и т.п.

Comment: кстати, с точки зрения smtp-сервера — **все** сообщения для него являются **сначала** входящими, а **после** принятия решения о способе доставки (передать другому smtp-серверу, сохранить в файл, передать фильтру) — исходящими.

Comment: А Dovecot-ом можно ли это делать? Хотелось бы пример увидеть, а не просто на словах.

Comment: примеры для, например, procmail и sieve, приведёны прямо в википедийных статьях: [1](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procmail), [2](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve).